# Why do void pointers behave differently in this scenario when passed to functions other than main()?

Tags: c, pointers, void-pointers

This works :

```
int main(){
  char *pc[2]={"Hello","Welcome"};
  void *p=pc;
  char **pt=p;
  printf("%s\n",*pt);//Output : Hello
  return 0;
}
```

However this doesn't work :

```
void test(void *p[]){
  char **pt=p;
  printf("%s\n",*pt);
};


int main(){
  char *pc[2]={"Hello","Welcome"};
  void *p=pc;
  test(p);
  return 0;
}
```

I get the error :

> incompatible pointer types initializing 'char **' with an expression of type 'void **'

Notice also how changing void *p[] to  void *p makes it work :

```
void test(void *p){
  char **pt=p;
  printf("%s\n",*pt);
};

int main(){
  char *pc[2]={"Hello","Welcome"};
  void *p=pc;
  test(p); //Output : Hello
  return 0;
}
```

1. Could someone give an explanation of how void pointers really works ?
2. What's the purpose of giving the function test() void *p[] instead of void *p? Can't we simply assign void *p for every data types ?
3. Does the compiler make a distinction between void *p and void *p[]?

Comment: You will have to answer (2) yourself. Why did you write `void *p[]` ?  The version with `void *p` is equivalent  to the original case.

Comment: The answer to 3 is obvious: The compiler warned you, so it makes a distinction.

Comment: `void *` are used for abstractions in simple terms. They hold memory addresses; only a valid `callee` functions know how to interpret data at that location.

Comment: This is a FAQ. The TL;DR is that `void*` is the generic object pointer in C, but that doesn't apply recursively to `void**`.

Comment: Well I couldn't find a dupe so I wrote an answer. Maybe this could make for a half-decent canonical dupe even?

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Could someone give an explanation of how void pointers really works?

`void*` is the generic object pointer type in C. Not to be mixed up with function pointers, which are not compatible. `void` pointer conversions are described in the C standard C17 6.3.2.3:

> A pointer to `void` may be converted to or from a pointer to any object type. A pointer to
> any object type may be converted to a pointer to `void` and back again; the result shall
> compare equal to the original pointer.

So you can assign any object pointer to a `void` pointer and vice versa.

However, this special rule only applies to `void*`, it does not apply recursively to `void**`. A `void**` is actually just a plain pointer to object type, it doesn't have any of the special conversion rules above (unless you de-reference it). That `void**` is a generic pointer is a common misconception.

(So common that it even infamously made it into the [CUDA API](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1g37d37965bfb4803b6d4e59ff26856356), which was a library design bug - calling this with for example `char**` as parameter is a C language constraint violation.)

Furthermore, any *type qualifiers* (`const`, `volatile`) need to be respected:

```
void* v;
const void* cv=v; // ok
v = cv; // not ok

int* i;
v = i;  // ok
cv = i; // ok
i = v;  // ok;
i = cv; // not ok
```

Formally this is stated in the rules of the assignment operators, C17 6.5.16.1:

> - the left operand has atomic, qualified, or unqualified pointer type, and (considering
>   the type the left operand would have after lvalue conversion) one operand is a pointer
>   to an object type, and the other is a pointer to a qualified or unqualified version of
>   void, and the type pointed to by the left has all the qualifiers of the type pointed to
>   by the right;

---

> 2. What's the purpose of giving the function test() void *p[] instead of void *p? Can't we simply assign void *p for every data types ?

There is no apparent reason to do that unless you for example expect to return a `void` pointer through the parameter:

```
void my_malloc(void** ptr)
{
  *ptr = malloc(123);
}
```

Alternatively you might want to use `void**` in order to pass an array of `void` pointers to a function. You *could* also use a `void*` for that, but it's a bit strange. Note for example that C standard lib function `bsearch` has this API:

```
void *bsearch(const void *key, const void *base, ...
```

We can pass a `base` array to this function where the array is an array of pointers, strings for example. As long as we are using some manner of object pointer and converting it to a void pointer, anything goes.

---

> 3. Does the compiler make a distinction between void *p and void *p[]?

Yes, as explained above they are different types. A `void *p[]` array when part of a function parameter list "decays" like any array into a `void**`.